# Scroll Load More SQL Limit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

So I have this website laid out and made but now I need to load more results on scroll. This has been asked on here a million times but I was wondering if there was a simple way to fit into my build. Ideally I'd like to do something with the limit but everything I've seen has been about having an entirely seperate page.

Page example-

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Products` ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,4 ";

echo    "<div class=\"full_container\">";
echo        "<div class=\"full\">";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo            "<div class=\"item_frame\">";
echo                "<div class=\"item\">";
echo                    "<h5>".$row["Name"]."</h5>";
echo                "</div>"; #Item End#
echo            "</div>"; #Item_Frame End#
```

JS example-

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {

///Where I would have the limit fix

}
});
```

Would this be able to easily be switched to be able to load more on scroll or do I have to go with the second php page to go with ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get more information you would probably have to do a call via ajax and then render the new images with the javascript once the data is returned. You could treat this in the same way you would for regular pagination, just remember how many results you've got and enter that into your limit so something like

```
(function () {
  var page = 2,
      uri = 'moreImages.php';

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {

      $.get (uri, {page: page}, function (data) {
        page ++;
        $('#container').append (data);
      });

    }
  });
}) ();
```

Then in your PHP page you just need to work out the offset based on your pagination rules

```
$page = (int) @$_GET['page'] ?: 1;

$numItems = 4;
$start = ($page - 1) * $numItems;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Products` ORDER BY id LIMIT {$start}, {$numItems}";
```

**Almost forgot:**
It might also be worth sending the request a bit before they get to the bottom of the page to speed things up. Make sure to set a flag in your code to mark that you're waiting for the information and only request more when it's clear or you'll constantly be sending requests while scrolling about.